# How to programmatically generate a TypeScript declaration file containing only types used in input file and its imports?

Tags: typescript

I want to use ChatGPT to generate code, but it's difficult to provide the necessary context when working in large codebases. I work in Typescript and I'd like to find a workflow where I can quickly provide relevant types in the prompt to provide it sufficient context.

**Is there a programmatic way to generate a Typescript declaration file that includes all types used in a given Typescript file and its imported modules?**

- Assume that you're working in an existing project with other files that may or may not be relevant.
- The resultant file should use tree shaking to only include relevant types to minimize context.
- It should generate a single file (easier to provide ChatGPT in a prompt) that includes the types of the file and the file's dependencies, including those in `node_modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for https://api-extractor.com/

It is analog of Webpack but for type definitions

Check output example at https://api-extractor.com/pages/overview/demo_rollup/

Answer (score 0):

`tsc MyFile.ts --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --outFile out.d.ts`

This will recursively scan all imports from `MyFile.ts` and all it's imported files. And outout all declarations into `out.d.ts`.

Alternatively you can edit `tsconfig.json` or create new one which has only one file included like `"files": [ "./main.ts" ]` And the use command

`tsc -project tsconfig.alldts.json  --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --outFile all.d.ts`

This method is better because specific other settings and not need to specify them every time. (e.g. strictness settings which affect how null/undefined types are handled).

(This method can also be used to generate .js files included only the `main.ts` or some other file of your app.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This will generate a declaration file that includes the types of the imported modules but it (1) includes types that are not used and (2) isn't a completely flat file. In out.d.ts, within each module declaration those also have imports.

Comment: I dont think ‘tsc’ will do that. Some bundler might be able as this info is probably available on API. In case you use large files splitting them would help. The GPT 4 can consume much larger inputs so this might not be an issue.

Comment: "The GPT 4 can consume much larger inputs so this might not be an issue." agreed that this helps, but would like to reduce input size wherever possible to minimize cost