# Generate type which has all "subtypes" resolved in one file

Tags: typescript

I am wondering whether there is a way to generate a type without dependencies to other files from a type. E.g.:

```
// file A.ts
export type A_Type = { some: string }

// file B.ts
export type B_Type = { someOther: string }

// file C.ts
import type { A_Type } from './A.ts'
import type { B_Type } from './B.ts'

export type C_Final = A_Type | B_Type
```

I am looking for a way to create one file which imports the content of all files and creates one export like so:

```
// C_Compiled.js (filename does not matter to me)

export type C_Final =  { some: string } | { someOther: string }
```

I tried using [dts-gen](https://github.com/microsoft/dts-gen) and `tsc` with which I was able to generate .d.ts files which I could probably also work with but I would have to do a lot of manual manipulation.

Comment: I believe this might have been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75842559